# Calculating standard deviation of the output of a numerical experiment

Tags: standard-deviation, simulation

I am simulating a game of Roulette (in `R`), where I simulate a gambler that starts with £100, spins the wheel 10 times according to some strategy (e.g. bet £5 each spin on red).  At the end of this simulation the bank balance will be either higher or lower than £100.  If higher, the spin is considered a win, otherwise a loss.

By running the above 100 times, I can calculate the proportion of times where a win occurred, and present this as a number between 0 and 1.  My question is how can I apply a standard deviation to this number?  Do I need to simulate the above (simulations of simulations) many more times to do so?

Because that would take a while...

Comment: How many times do you want to run the simulation? I'd imagine R code would get an answer relatively quickly, but can't say without seeing your code.

Comment: If this simulation is slow, I suspect your code isn't optimal. Not sufficiently vectorized? Why restrict yourself to the number of "winnes" instead of actually working with the amount of money won or lost?

Answer (score 4):

Your outcome random variable has [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=100$ (number of simulations) and $p=$ whatever your win chance is. For a binomial distribution the average is $p$, and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$.

Comment: I suspect you should be dividing by $n$ (or something similar, since $p$ is unknown and you only have simulation results) rather than multiplying. The variance of the sample mean tends to fall as the sample size increases.

Comment: The standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ is that of the number of wins, not that of the proportion of wins. Note that on the other end your average DOES refer to the proportion of wins. You have to divide that formula through $n$, which is equivalent to dividing $p(1-p)$ by $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @Erik What you mean is the standard deviation of the binomial random variable X is √[np(1-p)] and therefor the sample proportion X/n has standard deviation= (standard deviation of X)/n or √[p(1-p)/n]

Comment: I agree with @Erik - he outcome is the proportion of wins, not the number of wins, so the standard deviation you mention should be divided by $n$. The real issue is, in practice, you do not know $p$, so how can you use this information to deduce the standard deviation of $\hat p$ in the OP's original question?